# Llenar arrayList desde Base de Datos en Java

Tags: java, mysql, arraylist

Estoy intentando hacer un software a modo didáctico, para llenar un arrayList de Java con los datos de una tabla de base de datos. He conseguido llenarlo por lo que parece, porque el `system.out.println` me muestra tres objectos que son los tres objetos que hay en la base de datos. Una vez lleno el arrayList quiero mostrar su contenido pero me devuelve el nombre de las columnas igualado al número de objetos que hay. Me podíais enseñar como se hace??

Adjunto código:

Antes de empezar a leer ya que que habría que separar el código en clases y todo eso, pero era solo por probar. ya que la siguiente prueba será hacer esto mismo pero volcando los datos en `JTextField`. Sin más el código.

```
public class PruebaArrayListSerializable {
    protected static ArrayList<Object> badeDatos = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        MySQL mysql = new MySQL();
        ResultSet rs = null;
        //Object[][] obj = null;

        mysql.MySQLConnection("root", "1234", "pedidos");

        String sql = "SELECT * FROM clientes";

        rs = mysql.consultar(sql);

        ResultSetMetaData rsmd = null;

        rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
        int columnas = rsmd.getColumnCount();

            while(rs.next()){
                HashMap row = new HashMap();
                badeDatos.add(row);

                for(int i=1; i<=columnas;i++){
                    row.put(rsmd.getColumnName(i), rsmd.getColumnCount());

                }

            }  

           for(Object o : badeDatos) {
               System.out.println(o.toString());
           }

        }
```

Gracias de ante mano

---

Adjunto foto del código y la salida
[image: código y salida]

Comment: lo que necesitas es pasar objetos desde la base de datos a un array list?
usando json podes obtener la tabla como un array de objetos (cada objeto es un registro) y podes tener una clase (por ejemplo personas) a la que podes instanciar, cargar sus vairiables obteniendo (desde el json obtenido) cada registro (recorrer el json obteniendo cada elemento quenecesites). Luego crear un array list parametrizado para la clase persona donde cargar cada objeto generado y asi estaria solucionado el problema...o por lo menos eso entiend de lo que escribiste antes

Answer (score 1):

lo que necesitas es un arrayList personalizado que reciba los datos, cuando yo estaba trabajando para utilizar un arrayList, este enlace me ayudó, espero que a ti también te sea de ayuda:
[Enlace](http://www.proyectosimio.com/es/programacion-android-listview-adapter-personalizado-i/)

(el enlace no es de mi autoría)
Edit: Hay una parte en el código mostrado en el enlace que realiza lo siguiente:

```
animales.add(new Animal("aguila", R.drawable.aguila));
```

Lo que tienes que hacer para que funcione con tus campos, es modificar la clase "Animal" poniendo los campos que necesites, y al momento de realizar la inserción a la clase, puedes hacer algo tipo:

```
for (int i = 0; i < columnas; i++) {
                badeDatos.add(new ClaseParaArrayList(Campo1,Campo2,Campo3));
            }
```

Comment: Gracias por tu pronta respuesta, le he estado echando un vistazo, pero enseña como llenar un arrayList estático, es decir con unos datos preestablecidos... yo lo que quiero es sacar los datos de mi base de datos, que ya lo he conseguido, y luego, mostrar el contenido del arrayList con un toString simplemente. y este, me devuelve ya los objetos de la base de datos... pero no su contendio. es decir me aparece DNI=3 que es el número de objetos de la base de datos, digo esto, porque en el nombre me muestra lo mismo, no me aparece dni='44444' por ejemplo...

Comment: edité la pregunta con cambios que yo realizé para que funcione como deseas, en el modo que yo lo utilizo obtengo datos desde webService, pero creo que de la manera en la que te lo plantee te será útil

Comment: según lo que tu me has adjuntado, entiendo, que necesito una clase cliente, en mi caso, y de ahí instanciar un nuevo cliente, etc... Pero yo lo que quiero es más sencillo que todo eso... solo es hacer un toString de los datos que ya tiene el ArryList... No se si lo estoy entendiendo bien o no...

Comment: lo que acabo de hacer, me muestra un resultado aproximado de lo que realmente debería de aparecer. adjunto código<br/> [code] while(rs.next()){
                HashMap row = new HashMap();
                badeDatos.add(row);
                
                for(int i=1; i<=columnas;i++){
                    row.put(rsmd.getColumnName(i), rsmd.getColumnCount());

                    for(Object o : badeDatos){
                        System.out.println(rs.getString(i));
                    }
                }
            }           
        }[code/]